# Str object is not callable

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I tried to lookout for a way to split a string to a dictionary.

```
a=(get_profile_data()['1'])
print(a)
# output: CSRP:Hot12345,Pos:[id],Erp:Hot123456,Miki:[id],Citrix:Hot12345
```

I came out with this solution:

```
b= dict(e.split(':') for e in a.split(','))
```

But i get error `Str object is not callable`.
I don't understand why the error raised up, I will appreciate any help.
Thanks,
Or

edit:
full trackback:
    Traceback:C:\Or\myScript\txt creator\line_reader.py. line 24
    TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.

the strange thing is the code work fine with idle but show me this error in PyScripter.

Comment: Your code works fine for me on Python 2.7.5 on Mac OS.  What's your platform?

Comment: When you have a problem, make sure to post a solution that actually breaks. Because this would not. Also, post the *full* traceback, not just the last part.

Comment: my platform is Pyscripter 3.2. @Wayne Werner what do you mean 'solution that actually breaks'?

Comment: If I were to put `a='CSRP:Hot12345,Pos:[id],ERP:Hot123456';b=dict(e.split(':') for e in a.split(','))` in a file it would work. *obviously* you have more text in your file or you could not have this problem. The correct thing to do when asking a question is to post the smallest file/dataset that produces the error, what you expected to happen, what happened instead, and if there is an error message the *full* traceback - from `Traceback:` all the way to the end of the output. Otherwise we're reduced to guessing.

Comment: the stange thing is that the same code work with idle, but with Pyscripter I it show error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use a dict comprehension like this

```
{ k:v for k,v in (elem.split(':') for elem in a.split(','))}
```

Although it does seem that you overwrite dict with a string somewhere, so double check it.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you overwrite `dict` with a string somewhere. Fix this and it'll work.

Since it's apparently caused by your broken environment you can use this workaround to restore it:

```
dict = type({})
```

Comment: I edit the post, the code work on idle and show me the error in PyScripter.

Comment: Then PyScripter is broken.